# Unable to save string to log.txt

Tags: c, file, sockets, save, fwrite

I am making a chat program that that sends and receives information via sockets, using `recv` and `send`. Right now I am trying to add a function so it automatically saves the chatlog to a file. With what I have right now it only opens/creates the file, but it doesn't write anything into it.

At line 46, it prints "received messages" and 63 prints "own messages" in the chat. Can anyone spot my error?

```
  int ThereAndBackAgain(SOCKET *clientSocket){
    char keyPress ='\0',tmp[200]={0};
    int index=0, i = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[256];
    char nickName[10] = "Sneep";
    memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
    fp = fopen("chatlog.txt", "a");
    do{
        while(!kbhit()){

            if (recv(*(clientSocket), buffer, 255,0) != -1){

                printf("%s: \n",nickName);
                printf("%s\n", buffer); //Prints received messages

                fputs(buffer, fp);

                memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        if(keyPress=tmp[index++]=getch()){
            if(keyPress == '\r'){ // if user presses enter

                for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++){
                    if (i == 0)
                        printf("\b ");
                    else
                        printf("\b\b ");
                }
                i = 0;
                //print the message to a good spot on the screen
                printf("\b%s\n",buffer); // Prints own messages
                send(*(clientSocket),buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
                memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
            }
            buffer[i] = keyPress;
            printf("%c", keyPress);
            if(keyPress == '\b'){ // if user presses backspace
                printf(" \b");
                buffer[i-1] = ' ';
                i--;
            }
            else{
                i++;
            }
        }

    }while(buffer[0] != '#');

  }
```

Comment: Minor note: Avoid calling `strlen()` each time in the loop.  `size_t len =  strlen(buffer); for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {`

Answer (score 4):

The file is created because `fopen` creates the file. However, the data isn't saved until you do `fclose(fd)`. The C99 guarantees that if the program ends with `return` or `exit()` all open files are closed.

So, you shouldn't see anything if..

1. ...you are closing your program with SIGINT (Cntl+C).
2. ...the program is still running when you open the file.

Comment: Wow, i did not know that!  Is there any way to make it save before i close the program?

Comment: Yes, you could try to open the file and close it for every new append:
`fp = fopen("chatlog.txt", "a");
fputs(buffer, fp);
fclose(fp);`

Comment: You can also force to do it without closing the file with `fflush(fp);`. 
So you could do: 
`fputs(buffer, fp); fflush(fp)`.
For more info check [fflush](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fflush.html)